# JavaScript / CSS hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Would it be possible to create something like what I have in the code below with just vanilla JavaScript or CSS? I also want it to have the hover div stay open until a button click, which would then slide the original div back down.  Anything helps, cheers!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.up-down').mouseover(function(){
        $('.default').stop().animate({
            height: 0    
        }, 200);                        
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $('.default').stop().animate({
            height: 200 
        }, 200)    
    })

});
```

```css
.up-down {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
.slide {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.default {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.onhover {
    background-color:#1DB7CB;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="up-down">
<div class="slide default"></div>
<div class="slide onhover"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course it is. Have you looked up how to attach an event handler without using jQuery?

Comment: To add to the other answers, anything that can be done in jQuery can be done in vanilla JavaScript (though sometimes it's a pain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code as background, you can do it like this:

**Remember Jquery is just a library of Javascript, anything you can do o Jquery you can do it on Javascript.**

```js
var updown = document.querySelector('.up-down');
var def = document.querySelector('.default');
var btn = document.querySelector('.clickMe');

updown.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    def.style.height = '0px';
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    def.style.height = '200px';
});
```

```css
.up-down {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
.slide {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.default {
    background-color:#ccc;
    transition: height .2s linear;
}
.onhover {
    background-color:#1DB7CB;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="up-down">
  <div class="slide default"></div>
  <div class="slide onhover"><button class="clickMe">
Click me
</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I make the button inside the hover div, I tried putting it in there but then it messes with the slide down transition when you close it.

Comment: Try to move the button inside 'slide default', it should work there.

Comment: Still messed up, and it needs to be on the hover one.

Comment: Check the snippet now, it doesnt mess up for me, what happens in yours?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
.up-down {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.default {
  background: blue;
}
.onhover {
  background: green;
  height: 0%;
}
.up-down:hover .default {
    height: 0%;
}
.up-down:hover .onhover {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="up-down">
  <div class="slide default"></div>
  <div class="slide onhover"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sort of, I need the green div to stay focused once hovered, then a button click would bring the blue div back down.

Comment: Ah, okay... yeah you would probably need to use more than vanilla CSS in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listeners with `addEventListener`.

The animation can be implemented with the `transition` property so a change in height will slowly transition instead of happening immediately.

I also added the button like you requested in your edit.

```js
var updown = document.querySelector('.up-down');
var def = document.querySelector('.default');
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

updown.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    def.style.height = '0px';
});

updown.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    def.style.height = '200px';
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var isDown = def.style.height === '200px';
    def.style.height = isDown ? '0px' : '200px';
});
```

```css
.up-down {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
.slide {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.default {
    background-color:#ccc;
    transition: height .2s linear;
}
.onhover {
    background-color:#1DB7CB;
    
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Toggle</button>
<div class="up-down">
  <div class="slide default"></div>
  <div class="slide onhover"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Sort of, I need the green div to stay focused once hovered, then a button click would bring the blue div back down.

Comment: I added a button that can toggle between the two states.

Comment: How about having the hover one remain open, until you click the button. Then the grey one falls back down into place.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to create something like what I have in the code below with just vanilla JavaScript ?

Yes, everything that's done with jquery is doable with javascript.

> With css

It sure is. Here is something to get you started

```css
.up-down {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    position: relative;
}
.slide {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
}
.default {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.onhover {
    background-color:#1DB7CB; 
    z-index: 2;
    top: 200px;
    transition: top 0.4s;
}

.up-down:hover .onhover {
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="up-down">
  <div class="slide default"></div>
  <div class="slide onhover"></div>
</div>
```

So to explain the code somewhat:

```
.up-down:hover .onhover {
  top: 0px;
}
```

on hover of `up-down` put the `.onhover` back up.

```
.onhover {
    top: 200px;
    transition: top 0.4s;
}
```

Initial position under the grey div, the `transition` makes it so `:hover` will be done on the span of 0.4s.

If you want the div to stay blue when the mouseleave, just add a class on mouseenter. You probably still can do it with pure css but I guess it would be harder than this:

```
.onhover {
    background-color:#1DB7CB; 
    z-index: 2;
    top: 200px;
    transition: top 0.4s;
}

addedClass{
  top: 0px;
}
// target is up-down
target.addEventListener("mouseenter", e => {
  // element is your onhover elem
  element.classList.add("addedClass");
});

target.addEventListener("click", e => {
  element.classList.remove(" addedClass");
});
```

Comment: Sort of, I need the green div to stay focused once hovered, then a button click would bring the blue div back down

Comment: @DisplayName just saying, you have 5 people that took the time to answer you and none of them had an upvote from you. Upvotes are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS3 transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for height value of the div with `onhover`class attribute:

```css
.up-down {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.slide {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.default {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.onhover {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #1DB7CB;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-out 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: height 1s ease-out 0.5s;
  -o-transition: height 1s ease-out 0.5s;
  transition: height 1s ease-out 0.5s;
}

.up-down:hover .onhover {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="up-down">
  <div class="slide onhover"></div>
  <div class="slide default"></div>
</div>
```

To change effect direction use `top: 0;` instead of `bottom: 0;`